# How to keep many servers (5000+) up-to-date with git (and its rate limits)?

Tags: git, ansible, bitbucket, updates, auto-update

We're making a php service that will run on many servers, think 5000+. We host our code on git (bitbucket). We wondered what the best way to keep the servers up-to-date would be.

We figured either post-commit hooks (but what would happen then if a few servers didn't receive the update notification?) or git fetching every minute with cron. We want to go with the cron way of doing things, since it isn't possible it would fail, even if a server would be offline (either turned off or disconnected from the network), it would still resolve itself eventually.

We're doing a fetch every minute, and then compare to see if it needs to pull, if so it pulls and runs the migration code.

We would like to run this every minute so that the servers will be synchronized with each other as soon as possible.

Now we wonder, what about rate limits? We're using bitbucket, and the [rate limits](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/rate-limits-668173227.html?_ga=2.81300375.1487996773.1583850960-1638276415.1575748233) are 60 000 requests per hour (so a 1000 per minute), which would limit us to 1000 servers max before we will get problems then?

But it also says, if we make a public repo, we can make unauthenticated calls, the limits of which go by IP rather than per user, so we won't run into any limits then no matter how many servers we will have. Downside is, we will have to encrypt the repo then, then on pull, decrypt it and copy over the decrypted files.

Is this the best way of handling this? It seems very unconventional. What is the standard or recommended way of handling this (if there is any)?

Comment: Maybe that one server recieves the update and forwards it to other servers..?

Comment: Or just create more users..?

Comment: You could host the git repository on a single server, owned by you. This server will pull from BitBucket. The rest of the 5000+ servers will pull from that server. This way your control the limits/load instead of relying on BitBucket

Comment: You might have better luck over at https://devops.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @dan1st The servers don't know about each other. Could create more bitbucket users but a limit would still apply.

Comment: @Omer I think that's the best solution, to have several servers that pull, and have the other 5000+ servers query them to check if there is an update and to pull the update, either through rsync or by downloading a zipped file. I'll try asking the question on devops as well, maybe they have an even better solution for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it is not entirely uncommon to use it as one, git is not a deployment tool.  At best it marginally meets the needs of simple deployment workflows.  It is *certainly* not a mass-deployment/syncing tool, nor are hosting providers like bitbucket intended to serve the traffic for that kind of usage.

Even if you can find a way to make this work, as a user of bitbucket I would expect them to root out anyone trying to consume that magnitude of resources.  (Which, by the way, might have something to do with the rate limits.)

You should fetch each update once (or at most maybe once per datacenter, if your servers are organized in such a way), perform an build tasks on the server that received the update, and then distribute the resulting artifacts through your own network.  This is a well-established pattern with any number of tools (jenkins, teamcity, ...)

Comment: You're right, we should use something other than git for this. We're currently thinking about having several servers (separated from the 5000+ servers) that will pull any updates from git. Then the 5000+ servers query them instead of bitbucket. 

I'll mark it as answered and ask the same question on devops just in case.